# Weird shading on a bonnet of a car model

Tags: modeling

I need help. I model a car bonnet and overall everything is good, but there is a small weird shading that I don't know how to fix. Auto-Smooth is on, a bonnet line is marked as sharp, and I tried Recalculate Normals, but nothing worked. Maybe I don't understand something. Thanks in advance. Here is a link to a file:[image] and here are a few images:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you please share your file (at least this part)? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I shared my file.

Comment: you need to copy paste the link here  ;)

Comment: Understood, wait=)

Comment: Pasted into my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding something else to Moonboots suggestion:

After dissolving the 2 edges to even out the spacing there is still a little bad shading going on (see first image below) which if necessary, can be fixed by using the **Clear Custom Split Normals Data** option.

**Object Data Properties** > **Geometry Data** > **Clear Custom Split Normals Data.**

[image]

[image]

How did you arrive at having Custom Split Normals Data? When you selected the edges to **Mark Sharp** I think you must have done the following: with **edges selected** > **Mesh** > **Normals** > **Split**.
This results in the Auto Smooth Angle being greyed out.

Instead of using the above method to split the normals of the selected edges use the more usual : **selectect the edges** > **Edge** > **Mark Sharp**.

I don't really understand the difference between the two methods but just thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: Thank You so much!!! Your answer really helped me, because moonboots helped me a little bit, but the problem didn't solve. "How did you arrive at having Custom Split Normals Data?" - I don't know how it happened, most likely random clicking)

Answer (score 1):

You need to dissolve these 2 edges, they tend to flatten your faces:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank You) That worked.